# Searching LinkedList, comparing two "Strings"?

Tags: java, string, for-loop, linked-list, substring

I have a LinkedList where each node contains a word. I also have a variable that contains 6 randomly generated letters. I have a code the determines all possible letter combinations of those letters. I need to traverse through the linked list and determine the best "match" among the nodes.

Example:

-Letters generated: jghoot

-Linked list contains: cat, dog, cow, loot, hooter, ghlooter (I know ghlooter isn't a word)

The method would return hooter because it shares the most characters and is most similar to it. Any ideas?

I guess you could say I am looking for the word that the generated letters are a substring of.

Comment: Do the characters have to be continuous when you are matching with your randomly generated string?

Comment: What exactly do you mean @RJadhav? I don't understand the question.

Comment: so when you are matching hooter with jghoot the common string is hoot in both cases so max number of matches are 4. But if I give you jghoot and htosor number of matches are still 4 on character basis..which matching amongst this two you are considering?

Comment: @RJadhav I am considering the one that most closely matches the word. So the first scenario.

Answer (score 0):

use a nested for loop, compare each letter of your original string with the one you are comparing it to, and for each match, increase a local int variable. at the end of the loop, compare local int variable to global int variable that holds the "best" match till that one, and if bigger, store local int into global one, and put your found node into global node. at the end you should have a node which matches closest.

something like this

```
    int currBest = 0;
    int currBestNode = firstNodeOfLinkedList;

    while(blabla)
    {
    int localBest = 0;
    for(i= 0; i < currentNodeWord.length; i++)
    {

       for(j=0; j < originalWord.length;j++)
       {
           if(currentNodeWord[i] == originalWord[j])
            {
                 localBest++
            }

       }
    }
    if(localBest > currBest)
    {
      currBest = localBest;
      currBestNode = currentNodeStringBeingSearched;
    }
    }
```

// here u are out of ur loop, ur currBestNode should be set to the best match found.

hope that helps

Comment: I'm having trouble using this code.. when I try to implement it I run into the problem of converting a LinkedListNode to a string. Any ideas?

Comment: u don't have to store the best node, u can store the best string swell.. it doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

If you're considering only character counts, first you need a method to count chars in a word

```
public int [] getCharCounts(String word) {
    int [] result = new int['z' - 'a' + 1];
    for(int i = 0; i<word.length(); i++) result[word.charAt(i) - 'a']++;
    return result;
}
```

and then you need to compare character counts of two words

```
public static int compareCounts(int [] count1, int [] count2) [
    int result = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<count1.length; i++) {
            result += Math.min(count1[i], count2[i]);
    }
    return result;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    String randomWord = "jghoot";
    int [] randomWordCharCount = getCharCounts(randomWord);
    ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList();
    String bestElement = null;
    int bestMatch = -1;
    for(String word : wordList) {
            int [] wordCount = getCharCounts(word);
            int cmp = compareCounts(randomWordCharCount, wordCount);
            if(cmp > bestMatch) {
                    bestMatch = cmp;
                    bestElement = word;
            }
    }
    System.out.println(word);
}
```

Comment: This would work if I was only considering char counts, but I am also trying to consider relevance, too. Sorry for not making this clear. I didn't think about it like that.

Comment: Maybe Levenshtein Distance algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) will work.

Comment: Just to be clear: your method would return the word with the same amount of characters as the randomWord and ignore the actual characters of each word? It would only return hooters because they both share 6 characters, not because they both contain "hoot", right?

Comment: Yes it is true. If you are considering the order of characters, then you should use a similarity algorithm. Levenshtein Distance algorithm is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I think this works.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class LCSLength
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ArrayList<String> strlist=new ArrayList<String>();
        strlist.add(new String("cat"));
        strlist.add(new String("cow"));
        strlist.add(new String("hooter"));
        strlist.add(new String("dog"));
        strlist.add(new String("loot"));
        String random=new String("jghoot"); //Your String
        int maxLength=-1;
        String maxString=new String();
        for(String s:strlist)
        {
            int localMax=longestSubstr(s,random);
            if(localMax>maxLength)
            {
                maxLength=localMax;
                maxString=s;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(maxString);
    }

public static int longestSubstr(String first, String second) {
    if (first == null || second == null || first.length() == 0 || second.length() == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    int maxLen = 0;
    int fl = first.length();
    int sl = second.length();
    int[][] table = new int[fl+1][sl+1];

    for(int s=0; s <= sl; s++)
      table[0][s] = 0;
    for(int f=0; f <= fl; f++)
      table[f][0] = 0;




    for (int i = 1; i <= fl; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= sl; j++) {
            if (first.charAt(i-1) == second.charAt(j-1)) {
                if (i == 1 || j == 1) {
                    table[i][j] = 1;
                }
                else {
                    table[i][j] = table[i - 1][j - 1] + 1;
                }
                if (table[i][j] > maxLen) {
                    maxLen = table[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return maxLen;
}
}
```

Credits: Wikipedia for longest common substring algorithm.

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_substring